# How to make a complex chemical diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, chemfig, chemistry

I did everything possible to recreate this picture but I got stuck.

[image]

My best result is SOOO far from perfect.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %for font
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel} % for language

\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{R-NH_2}}{Первиний амін}\arrow{0}[-90]
\chemname{\chemfig{R-NH-R'}}{Вториний амін}\arrow{0}[-90]
\chemname{\chemfig{R-ONO}}{Алкіл нітрит} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{R-NO_2}}{Нітроалкан}\arrow{0}[-90]
\chemname{\chemfig{R-CN}}{Нітрил} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{R-NC}}{Ізонітрил}\arrow{0}[-90]
\chemname{\chemfig{R-N(-[6]R'')-R'}}{Третиний амін}\arrow{0}[45,3]
\chemfig{@{a1}CHY}
\chemmove{
\draw[shorten >=10p] (a1.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- (c1.east);
\draw[shorten >=10p] (a1.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- (c2.east);
\draw[shorten >=10p] (a1.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- (c3.east);
\draw[shorten >=10p] (a1.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- (c4.east);
\draw[shorten >=10p] (a1.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- (c5.east);}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

I assume that it might be better to use tikz because chemfig does not have built-in capabilities to implement everything I need. But still, if it is possible to do this only with chemfig resources, then write about it.

Comment: `chemfig` is basically `tikz` underneath, so using `tikz` for the extra bits might be possible. I've removed the `pdftex` tag because there's nothing in your question to suggest it is engine-dependent.

Comment: Does this compile for you? Because I'm getting a compilation error: `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator \`p' or \`p@' (in '10p').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.149 \schemestop`.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? For the error, just changing `10p` to `10pt` fixes it. Is there an issue adding additional nodes? When I compile, I'm getting non-vector fonts, which may result in poor PDF rendering, but I take it that's not the question.

Comment: There is an example on the last page of version "1.6e" of the ChemFig manual that may be useful to you.

Comment: @cfr Just type r (if you use pdflatex) in the terminal and you'll be done.

Comment: @cfr I'm stuck on the fact that they can't make inscriptions on the arrows and the creation method itself wasn't very "beautiful"

Comment: @CrocoDuck Yes, I looked at these examples, there are two of them, one is exactly the opposite of what is needed (the set will be collected into one element) and from the other I took the solution method, but again, apparently it’s impossible to write signatures on the arrows.

Comment: 'Just type r (if you use pdflatex) in the terminal and you'll be done.' No, you should fix your example.

Comment: Omg you are right the whole problem is that it says p and not pt. But unfortunately, who doesn’t solve the main problem (

Comment: No, but it makes it easier for people to help if you give them code that doesn't contain some other problem they have to deal with before reproducing the problem you want help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution without using floating objects, made from the last example that is in version 1.6 of the ChemFig manual.

I built two subschemes and then positioned the central molecule.

The subschema on the left is OK, the one on the right is done.

I used "mhchem" for small molecules and ions because I think it is better for this task

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %for font
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel} % for language
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
%\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\subscheme{
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-NH_2}}{Первиний амін}
    \arrow(a--b){->}[-90,1,,,draw=none]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-NH-R'}}{Вториний амін}
    \arrow(b--c){->}[-90,1,,,draw=none]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-ONO}}{Алкіл нітрит} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{R-NO_2}}{Нітроалкан}
    \arrow(c--d){->}[-90,1,,,draw=none]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-CN}}{Нітрил} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{R-NC}}{Ізонітрил}
    \arrow(d--e){->}[-90,1,,,draw=none]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-N(-[6]R'')-R'}}{Третиний амін}
}
\arrow(f--c){->}[0,2,,,draw=none]
\chemfig{CHY}
\arrow(f--){->}[0,2,,,draw=none]
\subscheme{
    \chemname*{\chemfig{R-NH_2}}{Первиний амін}
    \arrow(g--h){->}[-90,,,,draw=none]
    \chemname*{\chemfig{R-NH-R'}}{Вториний амін}
    \arrow(h--i){->}[-90,,,,draw=none]
    \chemname*{\chemfig{R-NH_2}}{Первиний амін}
}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt] (f.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- node[above]{\hspace{-2cm}\ce{+ NH3}}(a.east);
    \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt] (f.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- node[above]{\hspace{-2cm}\ce{+ R^{'}NH2}}(b.east);
    \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt] (f.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- node[above]{\hspace{-2cm}\ce{R^{'}_2NH}}(c.east);
    \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt] (f.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- node[above] {\hspace{-2cm}\ce{NO^{-}_2}} node[below] {\hspace{-2cm}\ce{(AgNO2)}} (d.east);
    \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt] (f.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- node[above] {\hspace{-2cm}\ce{CN^{-}}} node[below] {\hspace{-2cm}\ce{(KCN)}}(e.east);
    %
    \draw[thick,shorten >=20pt] (f.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (g.west);
    \draw[thick,shorten >=10pt] (f.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (h.west);
    \draw[thick,shorten >=20pt] (f.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (i.west);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with tabular

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-NH_2}}{Первиний амін}
    \arrow(aa1.mid east--){0[+ \chemfig{NH_3}]}[,1.2]
    \schemestop
    & \rule{5em}{0pt} &
    \schemestart
    \vphantom{\chemfig{H_2}}\arrow(--aa2.mid west){->[+ \vphantom{\chemfig{NH_3}}OH][(NaOH)]}[,1.2]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-OH}}{Cпиpт}
    \schemestop
    \\[6ex]
    \chemnameinit{}%
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-NH-R'}}{Вториний амін}
    \arrow(bb1.mid east--){0[+ \chemfig{RNH_2}]}[,1.3]
    \schemestop
    &&
    \schemestart
    \vphantom{\chemfig{H_2}}\arrow(--bb2.mid west){->[+ \chemfig{R'-O^{-}}][(\chemfig{R-ONa})]}[,1.8]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-OR'}}{Eтep}
    \schemestop
    \\[6ex]
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-N(-[6]R|')-R'}}{Третиний амін}
    \arrow(cc1.mid east--){0[+ \chemfig{R'_2NH}]}[,1.3]
    \schemestop
    &&
    \chemnameinit{}%
    \schemestart
    \vphantom{\chemfig{H_2}}\arrow(--cc2.mid west){->[+ \chemfig{R'COO^{-}}][(\chemfig{R'COONa})]}[,1.8]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-O-C(=[2]O)-R'}}{Ecтep}
    \schemestop
    \\[10ex]
    \chemnameinit{}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-ONO}}{Алкіл нітрит}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-NO_2}}{Нітроалкан}
    \arrow(dd1.mid east--){0[+ \chemfig{NO_2^{-}}][(\chemfig{AgNO_2})]}[,1.3]
    \schemestop
    &&
    \chemnameinit{}%
    \schemestart
    \vphantom{\chemfig{H_2}}\arrow(--dd2.mid west){->[+ \chemfig{R'-Na}]}[,1.8]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-R'}}{Aлкан}
    \schemestop
    \\[6ex]
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-CN}}{Нітрил}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-NC}}{Ізонітрил}
    \arrow(ee1.mid east--){0[+ \chemfig{CN^{-}}][(KCN)]}[,1.3]
    \schemestop
    &&
    \schemestart
    \vphantom{\chemfig{H_2}}\arrow(--ee2.mid west){->[+ \chemfig{R'-C~\charge{0=\:,20:3pt={\scriptsize $-$}}{C}}][(\chemfig{R'-C~C-Na})]}[,2.2]
    \chemname{\chemfig{R-C~C-R'}}{Aлкін}
    \schemestop
\end{tabular}
\chemmove{%
    \draw[CF-CF,shorten <=1em,shorten >=1em]
        (aa1.mid east) -- ++(2,0) coordinate (za1) |- (ee1.mid east);
    \draw[CF-,shorten <=1em]
        (bb1.mid east) -- (bb1.mid east -| za1);
    \draw[CF-,shorten <=1em]
        (cc1.mid east) -- (cc1.mid east -| za1);
    \draw[CF-,shorten <=1em]
        (dd1.mid east) -- (dd1.mid east -| za1);
    \path (za1 |- ee1.mid east) coordinate (ze1);
    \draw[CF-CF,shorten <=1em,shorten >=1em]
        (aa2.mid west) -- ++(-2,0) coordinate (za2) |- (ee2.mid west);
    \draw[CF-,shorten <=1em]
        (bb2.mid west) -- (bb2.mid west -| za2);
    \draw[CF-,shorten <=1em]
        (cc2.mid west) -- (cc2.mid west -| za2);
    \draw[CF-,shorten <=1em]
        (dd2.mid west) -- (dd2.mid west -| za2);
    \path (za2 |- ee2.mid west) coordinate (ze2);
    \draw[latex-latex] ($(za1)!0.5!(ze1)$) -- ($(za2)!0.5!(ze2)$)
        node[fill=white,midway,-] {\chemfig{R-H|al}};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it. Basic idea:

- use `Tikz` to create structure by placing `\node`s and `\draw`ing lines
- put chemfig statements inside the `{text}` of a `\node`

This should get you started.

#### Some general remarks:

- the lines can be drawn with more sophistication
- however, I use absolute coordinates (which hopefully is easier to follow for novices)
- I discared most packages, as I couldn't compile else
- please excuse my rudimentary translation from ukraine into some english terms (I think, you'll get the point)

#### About the code

You may want to use `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` to replace the standard tip by a nicer one (see the manual for many more details). See also the style section `[ ... >={Stealth},%       replacing standard tip ...]`.

The `\node`s represent the places, where some chem.formula will be written.

The `\coordinate`s just simplify some drawing of lines. (This part can be done more sophisticated.)

`Lines` are just drawn from `(remembered node name)` to the next, e.g. `\draw[->] (mid) -- (2.5,0);`.

For `pervAm` and `spirt` it's the same, just using more points in between AND I put a `node` on the same path `node[above] {+\chemfig{NH_3}}`  to place more formulas; this one places some text `above` the line, while the spirt part does it `below`.

Of course you can fine-tune more Tikz properties, see the pgfmanual.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%       defining styles as needed
        >={Stealth},%       replacing standard tip by a nicer one everywhere
        inner sep=3mm,%     make some more room around nodes texts
    ]
    % ~~~ building the diagrams structure via nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %     see ch. 10 for details (using with Tikz)
    \node (mid) at (0,0) {R-Ha};% to be replaced
    
    \node (pervAm) at (-6, 6) {\chemname{\chemfig{R-NH_2}}{PervAmin}};
    \node (nitril) at (-6,-6) {\chemname{\chemfig{R-CN}}{Nitril}};
    \node (spirt)  at ( 6, 6) {\chemname{\chemfig{R-ON}}{Spirt}};
    \node (tretAm) at ( 6,-6) {\chemname{\chemfig{R-N(-[6]R'')-R'}}{TretAmin}};
    
    % ~~~ a few reference points ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (pa) at (-2.5, 6);  
    \coordinate (ni) at (-2.5,-6);  
    \coordinate (sp) at ( 2.5, 6);  
    \coordinate (ta) at ( 2.5,-6);  
    
    % ~~~ some lines, with labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    \draw[<->] (pervAm.east) -- node[above] {+\chemfig{NH_3}} (pa)
                             --  (ni) -- (nitril.east);
    \draw[<->] (spirt)       -- node[below] {(\chemfig{NaOH})} (sp) 
                             --(ta) -- (tretAm);
    \draw[<-] (-2.5,0) -- (mid);
    \draw[->] (mid) -- (2.5,0);
    
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```